# Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial chapter 3 rails generate integration_test does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am following Michael Hartl's Ruby on rails tutorial. I am on chapter 3 at Test Driven Development. When I run the command

rails generate integration_test static_pages

it does nothing. No error and no spec files get created. I have installed rails using railsinstaller.

What to do next?

Comment: This is /not/ "too localized"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not generating files for you. It worked when I tried it.

Only one file gets generated:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end
end
```

which goes in `test/integration/static_pages_test.rb`

Comment: Can I manually add this file and continue?

Comment: Yes. This is the only file generated, and no others are changed.

Comment: The correct fix is given by Brian Dear below, add the gem 'rspec-rails' to development (or in my case, fix a typo when spelling development).

Answer (score 11):

It's a simple problem. Put the rspec-rails into the development and test groups of your gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

Then bundle and you'll be set. When you run rails g integration_test , it'll now generate the test files. The reason is that the rspec-generators are only exposed when the gem is also in the development group (as opposed to just the test group.)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The selected answer is only circumventing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would get no errors.  I have to use

```
bundle exec rails generate integration_test static_pages
```

for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (i.e. no error and no spec files get created) and EricM's solution does not work for me.  I manually created the following file in spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb and it seems to have worked (I had to create the requests directory in spec):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

This is the same code that is used in Listing 3.9 of the book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:TDD